# Android CTS: adb disconnects after reboot

Tags: android, cts

I've been trying to run Android CTS on my device. On my first few tries, I had success with running the test suite. I then tried to reproduce my steps and faced an error. When running CTS step 28/287 forces the device to reboot. After the device successfully reboots, the ADB connection suddenly disconnects and the test cycle ends early.

I/ModuleListener: [28/287] android.appsecurity.cts.DirectBootHostTest#testDirectBootNative pass

Any help is greatly appreciated. Please let me know if I need to provide additional details. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out why adb would disconnect after a reboot. I'm currently running Ubuntu on VMware. Once a new removable device is connected, a dialogue box pops up asking where to connect the device (Host or VM). If you set a connection rule, the device will connect to the specified destination after a reboot. My connection rule was to connect to the Host, which is why adb lost connection after a reboot. To change the connection rule in VMware version 16.0: Player > Removable Devices > Your device > Disconnect & Forget Connection Rule.